# Handle one or multiple words in Java Socket .readLine()

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, eol

I am building an application where I have a server and a client that talk to each other -<del>over telnet</del>. (via socket). The server program is monitoring a tank of some gass, and sends temperature level and preassure level via socket to the accepted clients.

I have managed to get the client and server to talk to each other when I write stuff --in telnet--, but...
**I need some help to handle the data that I send**.

I have made a loginscript to determine if the user is a valid user or not.
So I can write two words like "myname" "space" "mypassword" and I get a green light and returns a valid user.
But when I only write one word, and hit enter, it gives me:
*Exeption in thread... java.lang.Array.IndexOutOfBoundsExeption* EXEPT for when I write exit or logout!

(All users are hardcoded in the script for ease of use for testing. (The login script works fine by it self, and returns valid user = false when I write something wrong.)
Here is my code. Some pseudo code is added since I am not 100% sure of what to do...;)

```
String telNetCommand = dataIn.readLine();
            System.out.println(telNetCommand);

            String dataInArray[] = telNetCommand.split(" ");

            user.isValid(dataInArray[0], dataInArray[1]);

            if (dataInArray[1] == "\n") {
            //Ignore login request and continue telnet-logging?
            }
```

The client application has a button for each command, like:

"Send me every n'th data", or "Send me a batch of data every n'th second. If command equals exit, or logout - >  break operation....

```
// --------------// USER INPUT FROM CLIENT APP //--------------------------//

            // --------------// CONTINUE ? //----------------------------//
            if (command.equals("CONTINUE")) {
                continueSession();
                else  {    //..Kill session
                }   
            }

            // --------------// SKIP <N> //----------------------------//
            if (command.equals("SKIP_N")) {
                skipEveryNthData();
            }

            // --------------// BATCH <N> //---------------------------//
            if (command.equals("BATCH_N")) {
                batchEveryNthData();
            }

            // --------------// LOGG OUT #1 //-------------------------//
            if (command.equals("logout") || command.equals("exit")) {
                break;
            }
```

Maybe I am getting a bit confused now, but I think that I need to put all data  into an array, and check

```
if
dataInArray[0] == "CONTINUE"
dataInArray[0] == "SKIP_N", or
dataInArray[0] == "BATCH_N" 
(then send some data back)...
```

and...

```
if dataInArray[1] == "enter" ("\n") execute the single word commands ...??
if dataInArray[0] == "LOG_IN" or "PASSWORD" check if valid user is true..
```

Thanks for any help, and/or tips! :)

Comment: *"it gives me: Exeption in thread... java.lang.Array.IndexOutOfBoundsExeption "* => the exception message should also have a line number corresponding to the line where the problem occurs.

Comment: Yeah... I know. Sorry. It gives me an error here: user.isValid(dataInArray[0], dataInArray[1]);

Comment: What is printed by `System.out.println(telNetCommand);` when it fails?

Comment: It just returns exactly what I put in.  When I write "Demouser" "demopassword" it returns "Demouser" "demopassword"... If I write "SKIP_N" (or anything else of a single word..) it fails. If I write "logout" or "exit" it terminates normally.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Telnet, unless you are using port 23 or there is some implementation of RFC 754 somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys. I don't get any errors now... And here is what I ended up doing. 
I had to set it == 2 in order not to get any errors.

```
while (true) {
            String telnetCommand = dataIn.readLine();

            System.out.println(telnetCommand);

            String dataInArray[] = telnetCommand.split(" ");

            if (dataInArray.length == 2) {
                user.isValid(dataInArray[0], dataInArray[1]);
            }

            if (dataInArray.length < 2) {
                if (telnetCommand.equals("CONTINUE")) {
                    continueThisSession();
                    System.out.println("Running method continueThisSession");
                }

                if (telnetCommand.equals("SKIP_N")) {
                    skipEveryNthData();
                    System.out.println("Running method skipEveryNthData");
                }

                if (telnetCommand.equals("BATCH_N")) {
                    batchEveryNthData();
                    System.out.println("Running method batchEveryNthData");
                }

                if (telnetCommand.equals("logout")  || telnetCommand.equals("exit")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Peace :)

Answer (score 1):

The `IndexOutOfBoundsExeption` more than likely being caused by:

```
user.isValid(dataInArray[0], dataInArray[1]);
```

Make sure that the incoming `String` `telNetCommand` contains at least one space so that you have at 2 `Strings` in the array. You could do this checking the size of the array:

```
if (dataInArray.length < 2) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException(telNetCommand + " only contains " + dataInArray.length + " elements");
}
```

Also, on a different note, make sure to use `String.equals` when checking String content:

```
if ("\n".equals(dataInArray[1])) {
```

Answer (score 1):

In this part of your code:

```
String dataInArray[] = telNetCommand.split(" ");
user.isValid(dataInArray[0], dataInArray[1]);
```

You assume that the `telNetCommand` string contains a space. If it does not, `dataInArray` will only contain one element and `dataInArray[1]` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsExeption`.

You should check the size of the array:

```
if (dataInArray.length < 2) {
    //no space in the command - do what you need to do
    //for example an error message
}
```

Comment: So you mean that I should Swap if (dataInArray[1] == "\n") with if (dataInArray.length < 2) ? I tried to wrap  everything in one big "if" statement. if "one word" do this, else if "two words" do that. But still got an error (same error)... :|